# problems in clang-tidy configuration

Tags: clang-tidy

Recently, I saw a config file for clang-tidy as below.

```
Checks: 'clang-diagnostic-*, clang-analyzer-*, -*, clang-analyzer-*, -clang-analyzer-cplusplus*'
```

It first sets diagnostic and analyzer options, disable all options, and enables analyzer option again.

Is this a correct configuration?